# Trying to insert with Mysqli I'm getting "Using $this when not in object context in"

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, this

I'm trying to insert values into my database but I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtw1Y.jpg).

```
<?php  
    class Database{
      private $host;
      private $user;
      private $pass;
      private $db;
      public $mysqli;

    //Creo el constructor y llamo a db_connect, el constructor por regla se ejecutara primero
    // y la dejo publica
      public function __construct() {
        $this->db_connect();
        $this->passData();
      }
    // db_connect asigno los datos para la conexion
      private function db_connect(){
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->pass = 'mysqladmin';
        $this->db = 'mnote';
    //Paso los datos al controlador de mysqli   
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        return $this->mysqli;
      }

      public function passData(){
        $this->name=$_POST['name'];
        $this->lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $this->email=$_POST['email'];
        $this->password=$_POST['password'];
        $this->bdate=$_POST['bdate'];
      // paso la conexion y le asigno el query
      }
      public function putData($sql) {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        return $result;
      }
    }

    $db = new Database();
    $db->putData("INSERT INTO 'users'('name', 'lname', 'email', 'pass', 'bdate') VALUES (['$this->name'],['$this->lname'],['$this->email'],['$this->password'],['$this->bdate'])");
```

Comment: Which line is line 50?

Comment: `$this` refers to the current object (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) - it's failing when you're running the query because as the error suggests it's not referring to any object. Try storing the values you want to insert in their own variables beforehand and then use that in the query. Also escape your arguments or use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
$db->putData("INSERT INTO 'users'('name', 'lname', 'email', 'pass', 'bdate')
VALUES (['$this->name'],['$this->lname'],['$this->email'],
['$this->password'],['$this->bdate'])");
```

**is incorrect** because it's impossible for PHP to know which value `$this->name` refers to., which value `$this->lname` refers to etc.

`$this` refers to the actual object and `$this` must therefore be somwhere **inside** of a class.

**An example to clarify:**

```
class nameHandler {
private $name = "George";

    public function getName() 
    {
        return $this->name; //Returns value George
    }

}

$nh = newHandler();
echo $nh->getName(); //Echos out George

//Error. Using $this when not in object context ($this is not an object, but 
//$nh is because object $nh is created from the nameHandler class)
echo $this->getName();
```

> NOTE: Also look into prepared statements as mentioned in comments above.